# Kudan crash in Unity play mode even after correct API check

Tags: unity-game-engine, kudan

I've set up Kudan(latest version) in Unity(latest version) and have my editor key. When I try to run the default bundle or the angel sample, unity automatically crash. I tried all the [API keys](https://wiki.kudan.eu/Development_License_Keys) with the corresponding bundle id and none work.

Android APK build does work on my phone though. It only crashes inside the editor.

Comment: Unity 5.4 with Plugin 1.3? Works fine for me, having an incorrect editor key just gives you a grey screen, shouldn't crash the editor. And the editor key is different from the regular API Key, so you don't need to change those. Does it crash if you make your own scene and run that?

Comment: Yes it also crashes with my own scene. I will try on a different machine tonight and see what happens. I'll also try to reinstall unity.